# selecting and identifying a subset of elements based on criteria

Tags: r, combinations, subset

I would like to select a subset of elements from a whole that satisfy certain conditions. There are about 20 elements, each having multiple attributes.  I would like to select five elements that offer the least amount of discrepancy from a fixed criterion on one attribute, and offers the highest average value on another attribute.

Lastly, I would like to apply the function over multiple sets of 20 elements.

Thus far, I have been able to identify the subsets "by hand," but I'd like to be able to return the index of the values in addition to returning the values themselves.

Objectives:

1. I would like to find the set of five values for X1 that are the least discrepant from a fixed value (55), and provide the largest value for the average of X2.
2. I would like to do this for multiple sets.

---

```
#####  generating example data
#####  this has five groups, each with two variables x1 and x2
set.seed(271828)

grp <- gl(5,20)
x1 <- round(rnorm(100,45, 12), digits=0)
x2 <- round(rbeta(100,2,4), digits = 2)
id <- seq(1,100,1)

#####  this is how the data would arrive for me to analyze
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,grp,x1,x2))
```

---

The data would arrive in this format, with `id` as a unique identifier for each element.

---

```
#####  pulling out the first group for demonstration
dat.grp.1 <- dat[ which(grp == 1), ]

crit <- 55
x <- t(combn(dat.grp.1$x1, 5))
y <- t(combn(dat.grp.1$x2, 5))

mean.x <- rowMeans(x)
mean.y <- rowMeans(y)
k <- (mean.x - crit)^2

out <- cbind(x, mean.x, k, y, mean.y)

#####  finding the sets with the least amount of discrepancy
pick <- out[ which(k == min(k)), ]
pick

#####  finding the sets with low discrepancy and high values of y (means of X2) by "hand"
sorted <- out[order(k), ]
head(sorted, n=20)
```

---

With respect to the values in `pick`, I can see that the values of X1 are:

```
> pick
                    mean.x  k                          mean.y
[1,] 55 47 48 48 52     50 25 0.62 0.08 0.31 0.18 0.54  0.346
[2,] 55 48 48 47 52     50 25 0.62 0.31 0.18 0.48 0.54  0.426
```

I would like to return the `id` value for these elements, so that I know that I pick elements: 3, 8, 10, 11, and 18 (choosing set 2 since the discrepancy from `k` is the same, but the mean for `y` is higher).

```
> dat.grp.1 
    id grp x1   x2
 1   1   1 45 0.12
 2   2   1 27 0.34
 3   3   1 55 0.62
 4   4   1 39 0.32
 5   5   1 41 0.18
 6   6   1 29 0.47
 7   7   1 47 0.08
 8   8   1 48 0.31
 9   9   1 35 0.48
10  10   1 48 0.18
11  11   1 47 0.48
12  12   1 31 0.29
13  13   1 39 0.15
14  14   1 36 0.54
15  15   1 36 0.20
16  16   1 38 0.40
17  17   1 30 0.31
18  18   1 52 0.54
19  19   1 44 0.37
20  20   1 31 0.20
```

Doing this "by hand" works for now, but it would be good to make this as "hands-off" as possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to define a function that combines both criteria into a single number. Then you can start thinking about how to find the optimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.  You can change your definition of `sorted` to

```
sorted <- out[order(k, -mean.y), ]
```

And then `sorted[1,]` (or if you prefer `sorted[1,,drop=FALSE]`) is your selected set.

If you want the indexes rather than/in addition to the points, then you can include that earlier. Replace:

```
x <- t(combn(dat.grp.1$x1, 5))
y <- t(combn(dat.grp.1$x2, 5))
```

with

```
idx <- t(combn(1:nrow(dat.grp.1), 5))
x <- t(apply(idx, 1, function(i) {dat.grp.1[i,"x1"]}))
y <- t(apply(idx, 1, function(i) {dat.grp.1[i,"x2"]}))
```

and include `idx` in `out` later.

Putting int all together:

```
#####  pulling out the first group for demonstration
dat.grp.1 <- dat[ which(grp == 1), ]

crit <- 55
idx <- t(combn(1:nrow(dat.grp.1), 5))
x <- t(apply(idx, 1, function(i) {dat.grp.1[i,"x1"]}))
y <- t(apply(idx, 1, function(i) {dat.grp.1[i,"x2"]}))

mean.x <- rowMeans(x)
mean.y <- rowMeans(y)
k <- (mean.x - crit)^2

out <- cbind(idx, x, mean.x, k, y, mean.y)

#####  finding the sets with the least amount of discrepancy and among
##### those the largest second mean
pick <- out[order(k, -mean.y)[1],,drop=FALSE]
pick
```

which gives

```
                                 mean.x  k                          mean.y
[1,] 3 8 10 11 18 55 48 48 47 52     50 25 0.62 0.31 0.18 0.48 0.54  0.426
```

EDIT: description of applying over `idx` was requested; I want more options than just what i can do in a comment so I'm adding it to my answer. Will also address looping over subsets.

`idx` is a matrix (15504 x 5), each row of which is a set of (5) indexes for the dataframe. `apply` allows going through row-by-row (row-by-row is margin 1) to do something with each row. That something is take the values and use them to index the desired rows of `dat.grp.1` and pull out the corresponding `x1` values. I could have written `dat.grp.1[i,"x1"]` as `dat.grp.1$x1[i]`. Each row of `idx` becomes a column and the results of indexing into `dat.grp.1` are the rows, so the whole thing needs to be transposed.

You can break the loop apart to see how each step works if you like. Make the function into a non-anonymous function.

```
f <- function(i) {dat.grp.1[i,"x1"]}
```

and pass row at a time of `idx` to it.

```
> f(idx[1,])
[1] 45 27 55 39 41
> f(idx[2,])
[1] 45 27 55 39 29
> f(idx[3,])
[1] 45 27 55 39 47
> f(idx[4,])
[1] 45 27 55 39 48
```

These are what get bundled into `x`

```
> head(x,4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   45   27   55   39   41
[2,]   45   27   55   39   29
[3,]   45   27   55   39   47
[4,]   45   27   55   39   48
```

As for looping over subsets, the `plyr` library is very handy for this.  The way you have set it up (assign the subset of interest to a variable and work with that) makes the transformation easy. Everything you do to create the answer for one subset goes into a function with that part as a parameter.

```
find.best.set <- function(dat.grp.1) {
    crit <- 55
    idx <- t(combn(1:nrow(dat.grp.1), 5))
    x <- t(apply(idx, 1, function(i) {dat.grp.1[i,"x1"]}))
    y <- t(apply(idx, 1, function(i) {dat.grp.1[i,"x2"]}))

    mean.x <- rowMeans(x)
    mean.y <- rowMeans(y)
    k <- (mean.x - crit)^2

    out <- cbind(idx, x, mean.x, k, y, mean.y)

    out[order(k, -mean.y)[1],,drop=FALSE]
}
```

This is basically what you had before, but getting rid of some unnecessary assignments.

Now wrap this in a `plyr` call.

```
library("plyr")
ddply(dat, .(grp), find.best.set)
```

which gives

```
  grp V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12  V13  V14  V15  V16  V17   V18
1   1  3  8 10 11 18 55 48 48 47  52  50  25 0.62 0.31 0.18 0.48 0.54 0.426
2   2  8 10 12 15 16 53 35 55 76  56  55   0 0.71 0.20 0.43 0.50 0.70 0.508
3   3  4 10 15 17 20 47 48 73 55  52  55   0 0.67 0.54 0.28 0.42 0.31 0.444
4   4  2 11 13 17 19 47 46 70 62  50  55   0 0.35 0.47 0.18 0.13 0.47 0.320
5   5  3  6 10 17 19 72 40 58 66  39  55   0 0.33 0.42 0.32 0.32 0.51 0.380
```

I don't know that that is the best format for your results, but it mirrors the example you gave.

Comment: @ BrianDiggs this works great.  Could you describe a little bit about using `idx` in `apply`.  I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.  Any thoughts on carrying this out over levels of `grp`?

Comment: You, sir, are a rock star.  Thank you for the detailed explanations. Very didactic.  I don't have enough rep for an upvote, but one day...