# Identity groups on data frame based on multiple criteria

Tags: r, subset

### The Problem

I'm trying to find a solution to overcome a deficient experimental design in establishing sampling points.  The aim is to subset the original dataset, forcing sampling points stratification based on 2 factors with several levels.

I need a **general formulation** of the problem that may allow me to **redefine** the set of criteria levels.

#### Note

I've found examples of subseting tables based on criteria, the most relevant is a post from [Brian Diggs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9791094/640783) but I cannot find a general way to apply that solution to my particular case.

### The Dataset

My data.frame have 3 columns, sample id and two factors (f1 and f2).
Criteria are based on interval of values for f1 and f2.

```
dat <- structure(list(id = 1:203, f1 = c(22, 20.8, 20.7, 22, 12.1, 8, 
20.6, 22, 22, 21.6, 0, 22, 21.4, 15.9, 21.2, 19.1, 12.5, 16.6, 
14, 21.2, 14.7, 20.7, 20.5, 5.4, 19.1, 18.9, 22, 22, 22, 0, 0, 
22, 1.3, 1, 0, 9.4, 7.9, 14.5, 0, 1.5, 0, 20.3, 18, 17.3, 1, 
22, 0, 15, 17.9, 4.3, 19.5, 21.2, 21.2, 14.6, 2.3, 0, 6.7, 17.9, 
9.5, 19, 21.6, 16.6, 11.7, 13.7, 1.5, 1, 7.6, 3.7, 18.5, 13.5, 
20.9, 18.2, 11.5, 7.3, 6.5, 21.1, 22, 20.5, 20.5, 20, 16.2, 18.6, 
22, 15.1, 14.4, 10.8, 17.1, 5.7, 15.1, 12.8, 14.5, 8.8, 16.8, 
18.7, 1, 6.3, 1.8, 14.6, 22, 16.2, 12.9, 9.1, 2, 7.6, 7, 11.7, 
1, 1, 9.6, 11, 2, 2, 14, 14.9, 7.8, 11.4, 8.3, 7.6, 9.1, 4.5, 
18, 11.4, 3.1, 4.3, 9.3, 8.1, 1.4, 5.2, 14.7, 3.6, 5, 2.7, 10.3, 
11.3, 17.9, 5.2, 1, 1.5, 13.2, 0, 1, 7.4, 1.7, 11.5, 20.2, 0, 
14.7, 17, 15.2, 22, 22, 22, 17.2, 15.3, 10.9, 18.7, 11.2, 18.5, 
20.3, 21, 20.8, 15, 21, 16.9, 18.5, 18.5, 10.3, 12.6, 15, 19.8, 
21, 17.2, 16.3, 18.3, 10.3, 17.8, 11.2, 1.5, 1, 0, 1, 14, 19.1, 
6.1, 19.2, 17.1, 14.5, 18.4, 22, 20.3, 6, 13, 18.3, 8.5, 15.3, 
10.6, 7.2, 6.2, 1, 7.9, 2, 20, 16.3), f2 = c(100, 100, 92.9, 
38.5, 100, 90.9, 100, 100, 100, 91.7, 0, 100, 71.4, 100, 100, 
53.8, 28.6, 91.7, 100, 100, 64.3, 100, 92.9, 78.6, 100, 100, 
27.3, 83.3, 14.3, 0, 0, 9.1, 23.1, 12.5, 0, 100, 81.8, 100, 0, 
15.4, 0, 83.3, 100, 75, 7.1, 81.8, 0, 21.4, 84.6, 25, 80, 90.9, 
100, 71.4, 50, 0, 46.2, 90.9, 14.3, 66.7, 90.9, 84.6, 46.2, 91.7, 
33.3, 7.7, 71.4, 27.3, 46.2, 100, 100, 100, 60, 54.5, 46.2, 53.8, 
91.7, 100, 100, 66.7, 45.5, 57.1, 15.4, 75, 75, 76.9, 53.8, 25, 
90.9, 84.6, 91.7, 90.9, 100, 54.5, 23.1, 63.6, 30.8, 90.9, 92.9, 
100, 92.3, 90.9, 12.5, 38.5, 15.4, 84.6, 27.3, 7.1, 75, 21.4, 
7.7, 15.4, 84.6, 100, 69.2, 63.6, 64.3, 53.8, 92.3, 33.3, 11.1, 
61.5, 66.7, 23.1, 85.7, 81.8, 41.7, 69.2, 76.9, 38.5, 9.1, 23.1, 
85.7, 90, 100, 100, 14.3, 36.4, 84.6, 0, 7.7, 61.5, 25, 50, 100, 
0, 63.6, 36.4, 76.9, 100, 100, 100, 100, 90.9, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 83.3, 100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 54.5, 71.4, 100, 85.7, 
100, 75, 100, 76.9, 83.3, 100, 92.3, 33.3, 76.9, 33.3, 0, 40, 
91.7, 100, 53.8, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 92.3, 76.9, 23.1, 84.6, 
33.3, 100, 92.3, 46.2, 100, 9.1, 53.8, 7.7, 20, 42.9)), .Names = c("id", 
"f1", "f2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -203L))
```

### The expected output

Sampling points should ideally be grouped following a crossed design (it is not a complete factorial design).

For Factor f1: 0, 1-15, 30-60, 80-95, 100 
For Factor f2: 0, 5-10, 15-20

I need to find points given all combinations of f1 and f2 intervals, something like this fashion:

```
gr <- expand.grid(f1=c('0', '1-15', '30-60', '80-95', '100'),
                  f2=c('0', '5-10', '15-20'))
> gr
      f1    f2
1      0     0
2   1-15     0
3  30-60     0
4  80-95     0
5    100     0
6      0  5-10
7   1-15  5-10
8  30-60  5-10
9  80-95  5-10
10   100  5-10
11     0 15-20
12  1-15 15-20
13 30-60 15-20
14 80-95 15-20
15   100 15-20
```

The solution should split `dat` based on lines of `gr`.

This is not a complete factorial design since not all combinations will fulfill this particular criteria combination but it is important to identify NA's as well.

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if I'm providing sufficient information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cut`, to split `f1` and `f2` into `factor`s based on your breakpoints, `paste` the `factor` together, and then `split` based on the combined `factor`.

```
dat$f1.group<-cut(dat$f1,c(0,1,15,30,60,80,90,95,100))
dat$f2.group<-cut(dat$f1,c(0,5,10,15,20))
gr<-expand.grid(levels(dat$f1.group),levels(dat$f2.group))
names(gr)<-c('f1.group','f2.group')
gr$combined = paste(gr$f1.group,gr$f2.group)
dat<-merge(gr,dat)[c('id','f1','f2','combined')]
split(dat,dat$combined)
```

That will get you a `list` of `data.frame`, with one element for each combo defined in `gr`. You can them easily sample by these strata.